# Web - Detect gesture support

Tags: web-applications, frameworks, touch, standards

CSS3 media queries let me tailor layout to the width of a device.  User-Agent inspection on the server side let me further tailor content specific to a device.

I have briefly read (but not yet thoroughly researched) that frameworks like jQuery Mobile or Sencha may (or do) offer touch gestures as a form of interaction.

Is there a standard to determine whether a device supports touch gestures or not?  (With the follow through that I will then deliver touch or click controls to a user).  Is this best done  by the server, or are their client technologies offering this?

Comment: sencha and jquery mobile are still javascript frameworks my friend. check http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/touch.html for javascript detection of touch device. Server side detection can always be fooled. Like this one time i `Jsoup`ed some useragent stuff to make google give me the kind of page i want. javascript detection is a better approach. this approach is not fool proof either, we can only do so much with browser technology.

Comment: @Sreenath looking at http://modernizr.com/docs/ it would seem modernizr does indeed query for touch event support.  If you can make this comment an answer i'll check it as accepted.  cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sencha and jquery mobile are still javascript frameworks.

check http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/touch.html for javascript detection of touch device.

And talking about server side detection, it can always be fooled. javascript detection is a better approach. But it is not fool proof either, we can only do so much with browser technology.